# Migrating GIS questions from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, migration, stack-overflow

I've noticed there are some good GIS posts over at SO that would be worth moving into GIS.se. I don't personally have enough rep to do so, but I wondered if it's possible to flag candidates when I see them?

Candidates:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333395/arcgis-server-heatmap-for-to-identify-hotspots-on-a-cached-service.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303383/getting-started-with-arcobjects-without-aiming-to-be-developer
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625163/web-based-map-authoring-with-arcgis-server
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765833/where-do-you-get-arcgis-development-questions-answered

Comment: Now that we're out of beta, I flagged the posts above for mod attention, to move here (except for #2, which apparently I can't reflag because I already did so months ago).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will be more possible when the site leaves beta, which will be soon -- [timed to coincide with the ESRI conference](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262/sponsoring-a-community-member-to-attend-the-2011-esri-dev-summit).

So in the meantime, keep a list, perhaps edit your question here or add an answer with them.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism referred to in the [other answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/316/115) is called migration.

[What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

From what I have seen questions are migrated far less nowadays than it was thought they would be in the early days.  I think most moderators prefer users to think seriously about whether they want/need to migrate their question before requesting to do so.  The quick way that they can accomplish the same thing is to delete their question from one site and re-ask it on another.

Note: It is not recommended that new users delete questions lightly because this can feed into the algorithm for triggering question bans.