# Should we encourage more Stack Overflow questions to migrate here?

Tags: discussion, support

I thought I remembered [seeing a question about this](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3180/should-we-allow-the-site-to-become-a-support-forum-for-a-particular-software), (Thanks @Mapperz).
I noticed that the esri developer website has a link and tag on SO.
[As well as one to this site]
The question about using stack overflow for a help system seems to be answered in the link.

It seems redundant to have the "ArcGIS" tag outside of GSE.
there are 547 ArcGIS tagged questions but I get over 1100 questions when I just do a text search on ArcGIS on SO.
This [question](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/guidance-on-geographically-related-questions-belonging-on-so-vs-gis-se/1982#1982) seems to be related also.
As there will be ArcGIS sdk questions spread between gse and so.
Do we have a suggestion for this?
The main point is... If esri developer is recommending placing [ArcGIS] tagged questions about the ArcGIS SDKs and Runtimes on SO and there are many questions already on GSE.
There will obviously be missed answers, duplicate questions, and generally non-optimal use.
Should we recommend migrating all GSE "ArcGIS SDKs and Runtime" "coding" questions to SO with the ArcGIS tag or ask them to change.
or as originally stated "@Brad Nesom is off-base" just downvote this question and leave it like it is.

Should we encourage more Stack Overflow questions to migrate here?

[Esri developer website](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/support/)
[SO ArcGIS tag questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arcgis)

Comment: What it this question? http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3180/should-we-allow-the-site-to-become-a-support-forum-for-a-particular-software

Comment: Yes.  I guess the question now is... Should we ask them to move "into GSE"? Or do we need to start referring developer questions outside to SO with the "ArcGIS" tag?

Comment: What is "GSE"? Our site?

Comment: Yes, My apologies I see SO for StackOverflow and se for Stackexchange. I extended GSE for gis stack exchange.

Comment: On the other hand: Should we encourage _programmer-related_ GIS questions to move out from here and into StackOverflow? In https://developers.google.com/earth/forum/ "We’re moving our support forums for KML and Google Earth API technical questions to Stack Overflow". [Should i have asked this as a separate question?]

Comment: I've just seen this other meta question addresses my "On the other hand" question here: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/guidance-on-geographically-related-questions-belonging-on-so-vs-gis-se?lq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like PolyGeo, I'm having trouble understanding the core question. It seems to be *"Should we encourage more Stack Overflow questions to migrate here? If yes, how?"*. With that in mind:

- suggest revising the SO ArcGIS tag description with a suggestion to try GSE/GIS-SE/GIS.se  (note there are also SO tags for gis, postgis, arcgis-server, and ...)
- Patrol the relevant SO tags and add answers or comments with a pointer to existing discussions here on GIS when appropriate, meaning don't just religiously and by rote comment "ask this on GIS"

The main thing is to let the moderators and high rep SO users know that GIS.se exists, so they can flag and suggest moving when relevant. I bet most of them don't know about us, except as a vague back of the mind notion that there is something somewhere. The best way to raise our profile there in my opinion, is to participate there.

**edit:** Brad updated the question as I was posting. I also finally looked at the Esri developer site (should have done that earlier). It prominently suggests both Stack Overflow and GIS Stack Exchange as destinations.

[image: snapshot of Esri developer home page, 2013-Aug-23]

I don't think this changes much. While there is a lot of overlap, GIS has many end users and somewhat fewer developers, while SO has many developers and less users. In other words, I think it's ok for Esri to point to both. And I continue to recommend we active community members hang out and participate in both camps.

*((And to be clear, this is just my 2c, not a moderator decree))*

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/support/ does point to GIS-SE interesting ESRI are promoting our site silently (saves on support for themselves?)