# 2011 ESRI International User Conference

Tags: discussion, conference

The [2011 ESRI International User Conference](http://www.esri.com/events/user-conference/index.html) will be in San Diego, CA July 11-15.

During the ESRI DevSummit last March, GIS.SE [sponsored](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262/sponsoring-a-community-member-to-attend-the-2011-esri-dev-summit) [Kirk Kuykendall](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/users/59/kirk-kuykendall) to attend and he did an outstanding job of promoting the site.  Will they be doing something similar for the User Conference?

Also, are there any events planned for community members who will be in attendance?  There will probably be about 10x as many attendees as DevSummit had, so there should be a good response if a meetup is scheduled.

Comment: If Kirk's unavailable, I'll offer my services. I'm there all week.

Comment: I'll be there all week as well. A meetup with tasty beverages is definitely in order.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a past event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are working on making some GIS-specific swag that we can send to the conference.

Aside from that, what other ideas do y'all have to help spread the word about GIS.SE at the conference?

Comment: There are about 12,000 GIS-related ESRI users (consultants, government, you name it) that show up. If you've never been to the SD convention center, it's huge; they have lounges set up, cork boards for old-fashioned communication as well as "personal messaging" set up for people to interact with one another. The vast majority of the time is spent in "meetings", but there's a lot of walking between sessions. My first thought would be for you guys to create an 8x10 sign (for example) touting the benefits of gis.stackexchange.com that I could print and place everywhere. Just one thought.

Comment: Another would be t-shirt or buttons. Sort of like a walking billboard. (I don't know if I have any t-shirt transfers left. Have to look.) Business card-sized "ads" could be printed and handed out to people interested; it'd be better than having to look for a pen to write down the URL (plus be more on-topic and provide more info than just the URL).

Comment: I'm unable to attend the UC this year.  I think the T-shirts need to be specific to GIS.SE, not just SE.  Given the buzz around "authoritative" data, maybe we could tap into the anarchist undercurrent ... you know, the kind of folks who wear a button that says "question authority".  With that in mind, my suggestion for a T-shirt is: GIS.StackExchange.Com - THE Question Authority.

Comment: Who doesn't love free stickers??

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, yes - we are working on GIS.SE specific swag.

Comment: When people check in for the UC, they get a booklet which contains the agenda for the week as well as advertisements for some of the vendors.  Any thoughts on purchasing an ad?

Comment: @Seth I'm sure ad purchases wrapped up at least a month ago. ESRI seems to need a lot of lead time on _anything_ related to the conference (it is a big event, after all). Something to think about for next year, though.

Comment: Jim Barry promoted the site at the plenary session during DevSummit.  I can ask if they're planning on doing something similar for the User Conference.

Comment: That'd be great. Any time it comes from ESRI directly, the more likely people will be to hear about it.