# Meetup at 2012 Esri User Conference?

Tags: discussion, conference

Is anyone from GIS.se planning to attend the [2012 ESRI User Conference in San Diego](http://www.esri.com/events/user-conference/index.html) next month (23rd-27th July)? We should meet up or something! I don't have time to plan anything myself but will pitch in to help if someone else takes the lead.

Our kind hosts have are often willing to sponsor a community member to represent or talk about our site at conferences, see last year's [Sponsoring a community member to attend the 2011 Esri dev summit](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262/sponsoring-a-community-member-to-attend-the-2011-esri-dev-summit). A thought out proposal may well get financial support from Stack Exchange, even at this late date.

Regardless of whether a sponsored or organized event comes to fruition, I'd like to meet some of you fine folks in person if we're in the neighbourhood at the same time.

Comment: +1 - I would be interested in this as well.

Comment: Would be interested in meeting up, too.

Comment: Great idea!  Wish the fed hadn't taken away my travel funding!

Comment: I will be there, and sure would like to put faces to names!

Answer (score 8):

It's too late to give a talk or formal presentation.

Some random thoughts:

- Ask SE for swag--stickers, business cards, pens, maybe even a few t-shirts--and pass it out generously.  I *guarantee* you can get rid of several hundred cards quickly, because you have a captive audience of vendors in the exhibition hall :-).  It's great to have vendor presence here on GIS.SE: they tend to be experts in their own software.
- Do not arrange for some kind of gathering near the conference or in the hotel.  They charge way, way too much.  Make a reservation in a restaurant or bar downtown for late some evening and have people meet there. Use our chat room to coordinate if you like.
- If there's an app contest, make sure to attend when the contestants are present.  Pass out swag again.  Ditto for the poster presentation.
- If you're feeling subversive, hang around the "doctor's office" and pass out cards :-).

More on SE's support for conferences etc. is available on [their blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/).

Answer (score 5):

**A heads-up to those who can't attend or have conflicts with desirable presentations:**

ESRI is providing the presentations [online](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc12/tech-workshops.html) for free this year after the conference.  This is a change from charging for a single/ enterprise license for access.