# Meetup at Esri APUC in Auckland from 5-7 November, 2012

Tags: discussion, conference

Related to [Meetup at 2012 Esri User Conference?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/meetup-at-2012-esri-user-conference)

Is anyone else in the group going to the [Esri Asia-Pacific User Conference](http://www.esri.com/events/asia-pacific/index.html) meeting in Auckland on November 5-7?

I'd love to meet up if so. I'm happy to pass out any GIS.SE swag if someone can get it to me.

Comment: See you there Steve

Answer (score 0):

not sure if we crossed paths at Ozri or not, but ill be on the Esri Australia booth doing Dekho stuff.  Come say hello.  iLl have a GIS-Se sticker on my laptop :)

Comment: I'll have a [GeoRabble](http://www.georabble.org) sticker on mine